# Getting just updated list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm requesting data from server and if I post new data I want the browser to display old data + plus new but instead this is what I get:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadpost()
});

function loadpost() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/_loading_process/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
      })
      .done(function(data) {
          var dataArray = [];

          $.each(data.posts, function(i) {
            dataArray.push(data.posts[i].comment);
          });

          console.log(dataArray);
          $.each(dataArray, function(i) {
              $('div').clone.appendTo('anotherdiv');
            }
          });
      };

// output
// [1]
// [1, 2]
// [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I get it to just display the updated list and not displaying the old and updated at the same time something like this:

```
// output
// [1]
```

After posting new data:

```
// [1, 2]
```

Not:

```
// [1]
// [1, 2]
```

Comment: Not certain what requirement is? At `javascript` at Question a new array is created at each call to `loadPost`. Are you trying to create a single array outside of `loadPost` call, then push new elements to the single array?

Comment: Before i was trying to use .clone isntead of using .html because i have a lot of code in the html file. I want that everytime user posts new data just that one list show on browser but the behavior im getting is the same as the one from the console

Comment: @guest271314 yes sounds like what i need

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `dataArray` at each call to `loadPost`. Define `dataArray` outside of `loadPost` function. Either pass `dataArray` to `loadPost` at each call or define `dataArray` globally to `.push()` new elements to same array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const dataArray = [];
    loadpost(dataArray); 
    // at next call to `loadPost` pass same array: `dataArray`    
});

function loadpost(arr) {    
    $.ajax({    
        url: '/home/_loading_process/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'    
    })
    .done(function(data){   
        $.each(data.posts, function(i){   
            arr.push(data.posts[i].comment);   
        });    
        console.log(arr);   
    });    
};
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loadpost()    
});

const dataArray = [];

function loadpost() {    
    $.ajax({    
        url: '/home/_loading_process/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'    
    })
    .done(function(data){   
        $.each(data.posts, function(i){   
            dataArray.push(data.posts[i].comment);   
        });    
        console.log(dataArray);   
    });    
};
```

Comment: i tried using this code and at the end of it i tried to loop through the array using .clone but i got the same behavior i got from the console but in the browser

Comment: What do you mean by ".clone"? ".clone" does not appear at `javascript` at Question.

Comment: .clone jquery function

Comment: @quechon How is `.clone()` related to original Question? `.clone()` is not mentioned at current Question. All elements of the Question should be included within the body of the Question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok i see i edited the question but still i get the same result instead of looping through  one list it asks like everytime i update the list is like creating a new by the way the data is being pulled from database

Comment: What is expected result of second `$.each()` loop? `.clone` should be `.clone()` to invoke the function.

Comment: It was a typo i wanted to create a copy of a div tag and copy that tag for every item in the list which it is working but like i said instead of me just displaying the updated list the old one is staying in the browser plus adding the new list

Comment: Are you only trying to store and display only current `data` from `$.ajax()` call? Or, store all `data` from all `$.ajax()` calls, though only call `.clone()` for each of current `data`?

Comment: Trying to show just current data some how browser doesnt remove old array data when ajax call is made again

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? What is purpose of `.clone()` call?

Answer (score 0):

As JJJ said, You can't change the console output, but if you really want to store an updated list, you should do it from the server side, if you cannot change the code, you could store the objects an then iterate and update the array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourURL',
    method: 'yourMethod',
    dataType: 'yourDataType',
    success: function(data){
        dataArray = [];
        $.each(data.posts, function(index){
                dataArray.push(this.comment);
        });
        /* Iterate in the dataArray and append the elements in
        *   HTML nodes
        */
    }
});
```